# insert json file data to mysql database, having problem with "FLOAT" data type

Tags: mysql, json, import, floating-point, mysql-workbench

I have a ".json" file that simply has the data of some products. this is the file:

```js
[
    {
        "product_name": "TV Sony A8H 55 Inch",
        "company": "Sony",
        "price": 1698.05,
        "color": "darkblue"
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "laptop XPS 13",
        "company": "Lenovo",
        "price": 879.99,
        "color": "red"
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "laptop Alienware",
        "company": "Lenovo",
        "price": 1546.36,
        "color": "nightblue"
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "laptop ThinkBook 14",
        "company": "Lenovo",
        "price": 695.12,
        "color": "white"
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "mobile Galaxy A50s",
        "company": "Samsung",
        "price": 308,
        "color": "white"
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "mobile Galaxy S10",
        "company": "Samsung",
        "price": 442.21,
        "color": "grey"
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "mobile Galaxy S10 Lite",
        "company": "Samsung",
        "price": 459,
        "color": "grey"
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "tablet Yoga Smart",
        "company": "Lenovo",
        "price": 755.21,
        "color": "red"
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "tablet Tab4 8 Plus",
        "company": "Lenovo",
        "price": 582.21,
        "color": "firebrick"
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "tablet Tab M8",
        "company": "Lenovo",
        "price": 555,
        "color": "black"
    }
]
```

I want to "import" these data to a table in mysql database. for doing that I am using "mysql workbench". I do right click on the table name and choose "Table Data Import Wizard" option. the steps of importing data is doing and finally it shows me this message:
[image]

after a lot of "try and error" I finally noticed that the problem is that because the "price" data is of the "FLOAT" type, the "workbench" can not accept it. when I delete price data from my json file all records are inserted to the table without problem and the "price" column in the table is set to "null". how could I resolve this problem. I mean that how could I import "FLOAT" data-type from json file to mysql database. I do not want to convert it to "VARCHAR" and so on.

Comment: Use  `decimal(10,2)` - or the-like.

Comment: if you mean that I change the data-type in the table from "FLOAT" to "decimal(10,2)" , I did it and again the same message was shown.

Comment: Do not use wizard, import using SQL query. LOAD_FILE() -> JSON_TABLE() -> profit!